# Как поделить форму ввода на ячейки?

Tags: html, css

Вместо обычной формы ввода не получается сделать чтобы для каждого введенного символа была своя ячейка

Comment: `<input type="text" id="tt" name="tt" maxlength="1" />`  ну и стилизировать?)

Comment: А можно наглядный пример (или картинку) того, что вы хотите, а также если можно код, которым вы пытались достичь результата?

Comment: Картинки нет, в итоге нужно нарисовать форму из 13 ячеек для номера СНИЛС, в каждую из которой будет вводиться цифра.

Comment: Возникает только один вопрос: зачем?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str = 'Привет, мир';
var len = str.length;
for(i=0;i<len;i++){
  $('body').append('<input type=text size=1 value="'+str.substr(i,1)+'" >');
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body></body>
```

Как то так.

Comment: Вашу идею бы усовершенствовать и пойдёт )

Answer (score 1):

Чумовой теоретический вариант))

```js
function number(data) {
  data.value = data.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
};
```

```css
input {
  font-size: 22px;
  letter-spacing: 23px;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, #000, #000 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 35px);
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 0;
  width: 261px;
  border: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="" maxlength="7" onkeyup="return number(this);" onchange="return number(this);">
```

а если по теме: на реальном проекте я бы сделал отдельные инпуты для каждого символа

Comment: я думала про это, но на сервер-то потом все это пойдет как раз отдельными цифрами? или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: все цифры сложить в один массив и отправить на сервер

Comment: Последний символ не удается ввести, хотя так хочется.

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понял сути вопроса, могу предложить свою функцию, которая задает маску(шаблон) для инпута в формате `dddd dddd ddddd`, где d - один цифровой символ

```js
jQuery.fn.extend({
  setMask: function(mask) {
    $(this).off('input');
    var masked_all = [];
    masked_all[$(this)] = [];
    if (mask == '' || mask == undefined) {
      return false;
    }

    var input = [];
    var com_chars = 'dc';
    $(this).attr('title', mask);
    console.log('masked');
    $(this).on('paste', function(e) {
      var masked = masked_all[$(this)];
      var i = mask.length;
      var out = '';
      var data = e.clipboardData;
      while (i-- && out.length <= mask.length) {
        switch (mask[i]) {
          case 'd':
            cond = !isNaN(data[i]);
            break;
          case 'c':
            cond = diff.toLowerCase() != diff.toUpperCase() // checks if it's a char
            break;
          default:
            out += mask[i];
            break;
        }
        if (cond) {
          out += data[i];
        }
      }
      console.log(out);
    })
    $(this).on('input', function(e) {
      var masked = masked_all[$(this)];
      var diff = '';
      var cond = false;
      value = $(this).val();
      var i = value.length;
      while (i--) {
        if (masked[i] != value[i] && masked.length <= mask.length) {
          diff = value[i];
          var out = 0;
          while (!out) {
            out = 1;
            switch (mask[masked.length]) {
              case 'd':
                cond = !isNaN(diff);
                break;
              case 'c':
                cond = diff.toLowerCase() != diff.toUpperCase() // checks if it's a char
                break;
              case undefined:
                //return false;
                break;
              default:
                //masked.push(mask[i]);
                out = 0;
                break;
            }
            if (masked.length >= mask.length) {
              out = 1;
            }
          }
          if (cond) {
            masked.push(value[i]);
            var cc = com_chars.indexOf(mask[masked.length]);
            if (!(++cc) && mask[masked.length] != undefined) { // !!(++cc) - converts -1 to false;
              masked.push(mask[masked.length]);
            }
          } else {
            //console.log('asdw');
            $(this).trigger('mouseover');
            setTimeout(function() {
              $(this).trigger('mouseout')
            }, 2000);
          }
        }
      }
      if (diff.length === 0) {
        if (mask[masked.length - 1] != 'd') {
          masked.pop();
        }
        masked.pop();
      }
      console.log(masked);
      $(this).val(masked.join(''));
    })
  }
})
$('input').eq(0).setMask('dddd ddd dddd');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вводя каждое значение в инпут, фокус переносится на следующий инпут. Если есть необходимость стереть значение, то при пустом поле, фокус переносится на предыдущий инпут и значение стирается уже в нём. Поскольку по сути это одно значение, то по событию сабмита, надо его собирать из отдельных инпутов (в данной песочнице не работает, поскольку событие сабмита блокируется).

```js
$(function() {
  $('input').on('keydown', function(e) {      
    if(e.keyCode == '8' && $(this).val() == '') {
      $(this).prev().focus();
    }
  });
  
  $('input').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode !== '8') $(this).next().focus();
    
    if( $(this).val().length > 0 ) return false;
  });
  
  $('form').submit(function() {
    var dividedValue = '';
    
    $(this).find('input').each(function() {
      dividedValue += $(this).val();
    });
    
    console.log(dividedValue);
  });
});
```

```css
.block {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}
.block input {
  width: 40px;
  margin: 0 3px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
}
.block input:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px blue;
}
.block button {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="block" action="#">
  <div class="divided-input">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```